# Get the tail indices for several values at once in an R dataframe

Tags: r

Apologies if the question is a bit wordy, however I am sure an example here will clear things up. I have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(teamName = c("Brazil", "Germany", "Spain", "England", 
"France", "Spain", "France", "Germany", "Brazil", "England", 
"Spain", "France", "Brazil"), wins = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1), losses = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1), ties = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("teamName", 
"wins", "losses", "ties"), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")

   teamName wins losses ties
1    Brazil    0      0    0
2   Germany    0      0    0
3     Spain    0      0    0
4   England    0      0    0
5    France    0      0    0
6     Spain    1      0    0
7    France    1      0    0
8   Germany    1      0    0
9    Brazil    1      0    0
10  England    1      0    0
11    Spain    1      0    1
12   France    1      0    1
13   Brazil    1      1    0
```

which has some soccer countries, and I would like to filter this dataframe such that it only includes the last row for each team. Although there are 5 teams here, it is not necessarily the case that the 5 last rows in the dataframe are the 5 rows I want. In this case, there are 2 rows for Brazil before the last Germany row.

For this example, the row indices for the last row for each team are 8, 10, 11, 12, and 13.

Is there an easy way to get these indices without having to use a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Your dput and output do not match, your code gives 2 wins for the last 'France' row.

Comment: whoops, yes i was modifying the example and changed France from 1 to 2 to mix up the data a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in base R using `duplicated`

```
Soccer[!duplicated(Soccer$teamName, fromLast=TRUE),]
   teamName wins losses ties
8   Germany    1      0    0
10  England    1      0    0
11    Spain    1      0    1
12   France    2      0    1
13   Brazil    1      1    0
```

Comment: mmm yeah i know about duplicated and blanked for some reason - thanks much

Answer (score 2):

First, add a column to include row-number. And then an option is use `dplyr::slice` and select the last `n()` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(teamName) %>%
  slice(n()) %>% arrange(row_num)

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
# # Groups: teamName [5]
#    teamName  wins losses  ties row_num
#     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
# 1 Germany   1.00   0     0          8
# 2 England   1.00   0     0         10
# 3 Spain     1.00   0     1.00      11
# 4 France    2.00   0     1.00      12
# 5 Brazil    1.00   1.00  0         13
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(teamName) %>% 
  do(tail(., 1))


  teamName  wins losses  ties
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Brazil      1.     1.    0.
2 England     1.     0.    0.
3 France      2.     0.    1.
4 Germany     1.     0.    0.
5 Spain       1.     0.    1.
```

Or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, tail(.SD, 1), teamName]

  teamName wins losses ties
1:   Brazil    1      1    0
2:  Germany    1      0    0
3:    Spain    1      0    1
4:  England    1      0    0
5:   France    2      0    1
```

Comment: Also `df[, .SD[.N], by=teamName]`